# Using $key^{th}$ multiple of $\pi$ as a one-time pad

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, symmetric, one-time-pad

With a key $k$ of sufficient length, say 128 bits, is it possible to use $k^{th}$ multiple of $\pi$ as a one-time pad?

Please enlighten on the security as well as practical aspects (only if secure of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That is not practical since either you keep a sequence of the bits of the $\pi$ or regenerate them every time. You may need to store 64GB sequence if you want to encrypt such files.

   Then you need to multiply it with the 128-bit number. That is not practical, consider multiplication of 64GB number with a random 128-bit number.
2. OTP needs true random bit sequences like flipping coins, $\pi$ is not since the sequence is there! It is known to everybody.
3. In modern Cryptography, we use the 128-bit random key with a PRF to produce a long enough secure key-stream to encrypt the message like ChaCha. This is the way we encrypt messages. They are very fast like 3GB/s with AES-NI.

   No need to store or heavy calculation like you proposed.
4. It is not KPA secure yet CPA!. Given message and ciphertext, we can find the 128-bit key by dividing.
5. How the 128-bit key is transferred is not clear. The better way to use DHKE than a KDF than encrypt with xChaCha20-Poly1305 with this you will get forward secrecy - if you <kbd>DELETE</kbd> the key after decryption - integrity, authentication, and integrity where your scheme only may provide confidentiality.

Comment: Thank you for an enlightening answer. For 2, $\pi$ is known but a random multiple of $\pi$ isn't. Isn't that so?

Comment: That is a bit deep item to consider. 128-bit cannot provide true randomness, only PRP.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to treat this question as a strict one time pad one.

> With a key k of sufficient length, say 128 bits, is it possible to use kth multiple of π as a one-time pad?

That's 107 characters of description plus 128 bits of secrecy (plus $\pi$ which is a known constant). Your [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) cannot exceed 200 characters if you consider that:-

$$\pi = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{8n+1} - \frac{2}{8n+4} - \frac{1}{8n+5} - \frac{1}{8n+6}  \right) \left( \frac{1}{16} \right)^n$$

Therefore it's not a one time pad as one time pads are truly random and cannot be abbreviated in the way you suggest.

---

Something that might be of interest is [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-pad) link detailing all the various issues in using and improving the one time pad.

Comment: Paul, your answers are always very educative to me. Thank you so much for all that you do 